# PostgreSQL visual interface similar to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to view and possibly edit tables for PostgreSQL visually like phpMyAdmin, where you can see the list of tables, and fields and individual rows for a table. Is there any utility that can do this?

Forgive me if this is actually possible in pgAdmin III, but I couldn't figure out any way to see tables visually in pgAdmin. I have PostgreSQL 8.4 (I actually didn't install it myself, it was installed by another piece of software that utilizes it)

Comment: That list seems to specifically exclude data browsing tools – it's more of a list of GUI utilities, such as exporters, converters, etc. List of GUI/CLI clients: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sf.net) might work for you, if you're already familiar with phpMyAdmin.

Please note that [development of phpPgAdmin has moved to github](https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin) per [this notice](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/) but the SourceForge link above is for historical / documentation purposes.

But really there are [dozens of tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) that can do this.

Comment: Been playing with [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) since finding this topic.  it is quite fantastic for the occasional web-based database tool need.

Comment: This project seems not to be active at all. That last update was 2013.

Comment: For the record, @David is talking about phpPgAdmin, not Adminer which is a fantastic and well maintained tool (last uplate as of this comment : 3 weeks ago).

Answer (score 30):

I would also highly recommend Adminer - http://www.adminer.org/

It is much faster than phpMyAdmin, does less funky iframe stuff, and supports both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Its ui is quite intuitive. But there is some stupid issues such as json/jsonp data type is not even shown in the data types dropbox, but the last update was April 2015.

Comment: It seems like it can't create roles or change database encoding to utf8. Am I missing something? That seems like really basic functionality.

Comment: ps, PMA doesn't use iframes since 4.0 - switching entirely to XMLHttpRequests

Comment: adminer really has very limited functionality it is good for basic usage not for complex work

Answer (score 20):

pgAdmin 4 is a powerful and popular web-based database management tool for PostgreSQL - http://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: How do I view this info in pgadmin though? I'm clicking around under the Databases object and don't see where the tables are listed, or how to browse the data in the tables visually. The only thing I see is under Catalogs>PostgreSQL (pg_catalog)>Tables, but this doesn't actually seem to be a list of tables in the database - it seems to be something else.

Comment: Thanks. I see the list of tables, and that if I right-click I can View Data>View Top 100 Rows/View All Rows. Is there any way I can view the rows with a pagination option, like phpmyadmin where you click an arrow for the next page, without having to manually filter the rows myself?

Comment: Incredibly bad UX of pgAdmin made me switch back to MySQL. The world's most advanced database has the world's worst admin tool. That mess just destroys your productivity.

Comment: pgadmin has a very bad UX, I rather work with a basic tool like adminer

Comment: Nice ! However the documentation of  version 6 doesn't mention clearly how to bridge it with Apache and I thought it could only work in desktop mode. On Debian machines, the installation script can do this semi-automatically though : https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Studio with Postgres addin is the tool of choice to manage postgres databases for me. Check it out.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-postgres?view=sql-server-ver15