# Move database from local server to remote server

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-rds, psql

This is quite a general one, I'm trying to move a database from a local psql server on Windows to an AWS RDS server I've set up. The database is small, I'm really just doing it for the sake of learning how. 
The problems I'm having are as so:

-Seems like such a simple thing yet no simple solutions? (although I know/think if I had a linux system I could use pg_dump and cat dump. )

-I've gone into looking at aws documentation about how to migrate my database using their database migration service. However I've come to problems so early on that I'm close to believing it won't be worth the effort at my level of experience.

Seems like there must be a simple way and hoping the S/O community can help!

Comment: actually hold on, may have got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some tool like PHPMyAdmin, use `import` to import your database dump to AWS RDS.

If you wish to use CLI, than use some FTP tool to upload dump to database, connect via SSH and use CLI to import this dump

Comment: Is there a phpMyAdmin for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725216/postgresql-visual-interface-similar-to-phpmyadmin

Comment: Right, so you might edit your answer accordingly, since the question does not appear to be about MySQL. (Note, I'm not the OP.)

Comment: I used adminer which is a psql version of PHPMyAdmin.