# How to manually update a record in Heroku Postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a project on Heroku. I have installed Heroku Postgres. I have a users table, and in it the `role` field, if the value is `1`, then the user has more powers, if `0`, then they are limited. The default is `0`, now I want to update this field for a specific user, what should I do?
And is there any phpMyAdmin analog for Heroku Postgres?

I tried `heroku pg:sql` in console and wrote queries like `UPDATE users SET role = "1" WHERE id = "1"`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect your `heroku-postgresql` to a `SQL Editor` using the credentials provided by the `Heroku` in the `postgres` dashboard. After connecting to the `SQL Editor` you can update records in your `database`.

**Where `heroku-postgresql` credentials can be found?**

- Login to your `Heroku` account and click on the menu on the left of your profile.
- After that choose `Data` option from the dropdown menu.
- In a new window you will see your database running in the `Heroku` account.
- Choose the `data resource` you want to connect.
- Now go to the settings and there you will see the option `view credentials`.
- Click on `view credentials` and get your database credentials to connect it to a `SQL Editor`

> Please note that these credentials are not permanent. Heroku rotates
> credentials periodically and updates applications where this database
> is attached. But you have enough time to update your changes.

**How to connect `heroku-postgresql` to a `SQL Editor`?**

> I personally use [PopSQL](https://popsql.com/) to remotely work with databases. You can use it for free**

- In this case, I am using `PopSQL`
- Open your app and click on connect to the database. There you can choose `PostgresSQL` from the list.
- Fill important fields like `hostname`, `database`, `username`, `password` etc.
- Click on `Test`. It will show you output like `Looks Good` and then you can connect to your database. If any error occurred then you can see it in the output.

> If you are using ***Private or Shield Heroku Postgres Database*** then you have to `whitelist` the `IP` address from which you are accessing the resources. Read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-via-mtls)

To know about analog to `phpMyAdmin` for PostgresSQL check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725216/postgresql-visual-interface-similar-to-phpmyadmin/26552315) on Stackoverflow